# Distribute stock to customers using R Language

Tags: r, location, stock, distribute

i have a table with product code, Warehouse Location and Stock Quantity(Warehouse Stock)

| product code | Warehouse Location | Stock quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 |
| 1 | b | 5 |
| 1 | c | 3 |
| 2 | a | 5 |
| 2 | b | 5 |

a second table with the following information (Customers Orders)

| customer | product code | order quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 3 |
| John | 2 | 2 |
| Mark | 1 | 5 |
| Mark | 2 | 7 |
| George | 1 | 2 |
| George | 2 | 1 |

Is there a way in "R" to create a third table that will distribute the pickup quantity to the warehouse Location? something like table no3?

| customer | product code | picking Quantity | Warehouse Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 2 | a |
| John | 1 | 1 | b |
| John | 2 | 2 | a |
| Mark | 1 | 4 | b |
| Mark | 1 | 1 | c |
| Mark | 2 | 3 | a |
| Mark | 2 | 4 | b |
| George | 1 | 2 | c |
| George | 2 | 1 | c |